# Take a file from Windows to Linux via tftp

Tags: server, windows, files, tftp

I have created a TFTP server on Windows and I want to take a file with my Linux. But actually when I put a command like this:

```
get c:\test\test.txt
```

I activate my trace and I have:

```
Packet Tracing on.
tftp> get c:\test\test.txt
tftp: c: Name or service not know
```

Do you have an idea to resolve this?

I'm new on Linux so maybe I do somethink wrong. If you need more info tell me what you want.

Comment: wich Ubuntu version are you using ?

Comment: and how would ftp know what "C:" is? You "cd" to the directory and then "get" the file.

Comment: @Rinzwind is right. You can't get from "C:" as "C:" is how Windows associates drives and what not. You can either "cd" to the directory (probably /media/UbuntuUser/something) or connect to the FTP server you established with "get XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/test/test.txt", assuming you have your C:\ drive set as the root folder for FTP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TFTP predates Windows, so it does not use Windows naming conventions.  **No C:\ drive for you! ;-)**

Depending on the TFTP server you installed (Microsoft's?) and the version (which?) and what the configuration is of your server (config file?  Registry keys?)  you are "sharing" *some subdirectory somewhere* on *one of your hard disks*.

The tftp commands (type `?`<kbd>Enter</kbd> or `help`<kbd>Enter</kbd> depending on the server) actually look a lot like `bash` and the following are the most useful:

- `ls` Lists files
- `cd` changes directory
- `get` gets (=downloads) a file
- `put` puts (=uploads) a file
- `bye` closes the session

**Examples:** 
`get test.txt` or `get test/test.txt` gets the file text.txt *if and only if you put your `C:\` as the "shared directory" in the settings of your TFTP server.*

Comment: And as you're a reputation 1 user: don't forget to click the grey check-mark under the "0" at the left of this text, therefore "accepting" the answer, which is better then saying "thank you" as both of our reputations will go up!  ;-)

Comment: Hello Fabby, thanks for this information. Your answer was really useful for me!

Comment: I tried to do my best with the (very vague) question you posed.  Next time: add the version of your server, the manufacturer, ... what version of Ubuntu you're running, ...  :P  ;-)

Comment: Yea I ask this question very fast. I'm actually at my work and I don't have a lot of time. But next time I'm gonna try to give more information.